# Regex to capture single line comment

Tags: java, regex, comments

Using regular expression in java, I want to detect single line JS comment that starts with **//**. So what I come up with is -

```
[^:]\/\/.*$
```

Above regular expression is not capturing :

```
http://example.com
```

But its capturing highligted portion from following String (I can understand why) : ab**c//qqqqqqqqqq**
. But I don't want c (character immediate left to //) to be captured.

Also, I dont want below strings to be captured at all :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<%//Table for help essages ends%>
```

I know, this topic is diccused multiple times. But nothing is helping me much. So I am asking this question again. For testing purpose I'm using http://rubular.com/ this site.

Can anyone please help me.

**Solution :**

```
(?<!http:|https:)\/\/.*(?<!>)\s$
```

To remove other type of comments we are using :

```
<!--(.|\s)*?-->
\/\*(.|\s)*?\*\/
<%--(.|\s)*?--%>
```

**Test Case :**

```
http://example.com
abc  //  qqqqqq>qqqq 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">   
<% // END: Modified for Bug # 1070 %>

// comment
/* comment */ program //comment


var ok = "not really"; 
// This is a comment
// Shouldn't this be a comment too?

var one = 't "stuff"\' now.'; // comment /* hola */ // lol

/* multiline comment
// still
/* still * * * * / */
something here

'string\' // string'; // comment /* comment
/regex/; // comment */* still-a-comment
' /**/ string ' /* "comment..."
// still-a-comment */ alert('isn\'t a comment!');
/\/* this isn't a comment! */; //* comment
/*
    //a comment... // still-a-comment
    12345
    "Foo /bar/ ""
*/
/*//Boo*/
/*/**/
```

Comment: Use negative lookbehind, if Java supports it.

Comment: Do you have colons before comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have colons before comments,and comments do not end with > ,   `(?<!:)\/\/.*(?<!\>)$`
 will satisfy all the cases you have posted on your question.
If you do have colons before comments, you can specify
`(?<!http:|https:)\/\/.*(?<!\>)$`.

Or another solution would be `(?<!http:|https:)\/\/[^\>]*$` which does not match comments containing >, placed anywhere in line.

Comment: Hi Sparrow, its not working for <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">. Rest is good.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my answer. I hope it is fine now

Comment: I've upvoted you for your effort. There is still one problem. Same as before. Just add a new line after : <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">. The solution isn't working.

Comment: I've update my question with one more condition. Please help me.

Comment: you can try the second solution I just posted. It should work for all cases. Let me know.

Comment: Modified your answer a little bit. I'm using (?<!http:|https:)\/\/.*(?<!>)\s$

Comment: As you wish :) but that will not work if there are multiple whitespaces after > . If you do not have such a case it's ok

Comment: Ohh! You are absolutely right. I missed that. The solution you have provided is not working in some cases. I've updated my question with a test case. Can you please provide a solution that will work for all the test cases.

Comment: Hmmm can you tell me where it's not working. Or better could you put your code on jsfiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57233/discussion-between-sparrow-and-kartic).